# OAuth2 access token coming back as Null in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

Apologies if this is a silly question, I am very new to programming in general and I have never worked with OAuth before.

I am currently trying to build a Google App Script which interacts with an external service and authenticates using OAuth2.

I am having a lot of trouble with OAuth2... for starters, I'm not sure I am using the correct library for this. I am going off the one recommended by Google for ads script - https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/oauth20-library

I know there is another popular one available in GitHub https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2
I was not able to use it because everything comes out as 'is not a function', no matter how I add the library, manually or through the built-in feature.

I started building the API call, based on the first library and I had some partial success, I started getting back a 500 error message and I realized my accessToken is null.

```
    function SHICall(){ 

var tokenUrl = "X/token";
const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();  
var clientId = scriptProperties.getProperty('CLIENT_ID');
var clientSecret = scriptProperties.getProperty('SECRET');
var opt_scope = "CustomerAPI.Public";


// Access token is obtained and cached.
const authUrlFetch = OAuth2.withClientCredentials(tokenUrl, clientId, clientSecret, opt_scope);
const url = "X";


Logger.log(authUrlFetch);
var options = { 
  headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Accept': "application/json"},
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  method: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  validateHttpsCertificates: false,
};

// Use access token in each request
const response = authUrlFetch.fetch(url, options);

// ... use response
Logger.log(response);
 }
```

Any clue why the token is coming back as null? I based my API Call on google's documentation again https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis#oauth_2

Comment: I tried the script again with the GitHub repo after managing to fix it!

The token still came back as null after configuring the getOAuthService function and running it with no errors

function SHI_CALL(){
var token = OAuth2.getAccessToken;
Logger.log(token);
}

Comment: From what I understand the issue is  solved?

Comment: The issue is not solved, I am getting a 500 error code and null token when using both methods/ libraries

Comment: Have you tried the OAuth configuration outside of  Google Apps Script library ? Not reproducible from my side